# How do I programatically access Locale in my custom web part?

Tags: user-profile

I've been going crazy trying to find where I can access the Locale found by going to your username at the top right of SharePoint -> My Settings -> My Regional Settings

[image]

I've been able to access Theme by using this code:

```
        // Get data from SharePoint.
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPList siteUserInfoList = web.Site.RootWeb.SiteUserInfoList;
        SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;
        SPListItem currentUserItem = siteUserInfoList.GetItemById(user.ID);

        string theme = (string)currentUserItem["Theme"];
        //string locale = web.Locale.Name;
        //string locale = web.Site.RootWeb.Locale.Name;
        //string locale = (string)currentUserItem["Locale"];
```

At the bottom of that code snippet, you can see three attempts at retrieving Locale, but they do not work. Any help is appreciated; I've been wasting a lot of time not finding much with foreach loops through all the SPList, SPListItem, etc objects... :(

*** Feb 3, 2011 ***

Code is pointed out in James Love's answer below for successfully retrieving Locale from "My Regional Settings".

**However, this only works when "Always follow web settings" is NOT checked for Follow Web Settings.** (See top of attached picture.)

```
// Get the locale.
string locale = "a";
try
{
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo((int)web.CurrentUser.RegionalSettings.LocaleId);
    locale = ci.Name;
}
catch
{
    try { var locale2 = web.CurrentUser.RegionalSettings.LocaleId; }
    catch { locale = "en-US"; };
}
```

The code where I have `var locale2` will fail if "Always follow web settings" is checked, but otherwise it will work. That means that in the outermost catch block, I should set my locale variable to something else. I just need to find out where to access the overall locale settings.

Comment: Just as a pro-tip: learn to the use and navigate MSDN object model documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.aspx - and also, the Power Tools for Visual Studio 2010 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963- will help you dig out parts of the object model you want to find.

Comment: I also find Reflector an invaluable tool. If I can see a page setting a property, I can normally use Reflector to track through to see how that property is set.

(Except when it's a call into COM code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.RegionalSettings.LocaleID?

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. I just had to add a little extra code to change LocaleID from an unsigned int to the appropriate string for my use.

CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo((int)web.CurrentUser.RegionalSettings.LocaleId);
string locale = ci.Name;

Now when I change the locale as shown in the picture in the original post, the page with this code gets updated as well. So it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition here is a way of overwriting the user's checkbox.  (by overwriting their regional settings object)

```
SPRegionalSettings regionalSettings = new SPRegionalSettings(SPContext.Current.Web);
regionalSettings = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.RegionalSettings;

regionalSettings.LocaleId = uint.Parse(ddlLanguage.SelectedItem.Value);

SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.RegionalSettings = regionalSettings;
```

Then there is no need to worry about the box being checked and the user's other settings stay intact.